# Difference between var, let and const in nodejs and typescript?

Tags: typescript

Can any please explain the Difference between var, let and const in nodejs and typescript with detailed and examples?

Comment: https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e

Answer (score -1):

var have function scope. Even if you declare var in some block (e.g for loop), it will be accessible outside the block in which it is declared

let has a block scope confined to block in which it is declared.

Const declares the constant in a function scope. Its value cannot be changed

Comment: This answer is wrong, var is not globally scoped, it is function-scoped. Also, let and const are both block scoped.